# Stickness of sessions on a HAproxy balancer of nginx/php-fpm farm

Tags: session, nginx, php, haproxy

I am setting up a keepalived `HAProxy` balancer of http traffic in the frontend of a three appserver-nodes with `nginx/php-fpm`. So my chain of services would be:

```
   -----> HAProxy -----> nginx -----> php-FPM ----> webapp
```

Well, the problem is that `haproxy` can't see my backend servers when is set it to use cookies to ensure session affinity.

here is my haproxy.conf file:

```
global
log /dev/log    local0
log /dev/log    local1 notice
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
user haproxy
group haproxy
daemon

defaults
log global
mode    http
option  httplog
option  dontlognull
    contimeout 5000
    clitimeout 50000
    srvtimeout 50000

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    default_backend servers

backend servers
option httpchk OPTIONS /
option forwardfor
option http-server-close
balance roundrobin
cookie PHPSESSID prefix indirect nocache
    stats enable
    stats refresh 10s
    stats hide-version
    stats scope   .
    stats uri     /lb?stats
stats auth admin:admin2013

server nodo1 10.10.200.19:80 check cookie nodo1
server nodo2 10.10.200.20:80 check cookie nodo2
server nodo3 10.10.200.21:80 check cookie nodo3
```

Anyone has any idea why this is happening?  I already checked my php.ini file and the session.name variable has the correct value (PHPSESSID in this case).

In the other hand, i'm planning use a redis db as a session storage, i'm thinking that if I  choose this, would not be necessary to use session affinity in haproxy, but i'm worry that in this case, the user could been jumping on each server in every request.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the error, i had to remove the line:

```
option httpchk OPTIONS /
```

this was all the problem, now is working like a charm!

Now I'll continue with the connection of redis to ensure that the session of the user will not been lost in a eventually node crash.